# Exist a linear combination for full rank matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I met a problem this morning.

Suppose that there exists a full rank matrix $X = \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\ b & c & b\\ c & d & a  \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$. From the definition of [linear independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) we know that if the matrix is not a full rank matrix, a relationship would exist: $k_1X_1 + k_2X_2 = X_3$, where $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ are corresponding columns of $X$, and $k_1$, $k_2 \in \mathbb{R}\backslash0$.

If $k_1$ and $k_2$ exist, then:
$$\begin{bmatrix} X_1 & X_2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} k_1 \\ k_2\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} X_3 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$ \begin{bmatrix} k_1 \\ k_2\end{bmatrix}  = pinv (\begin{bmatrix} X_1 & X_2\end{bmatrix}) \begin{bmatrix} X_3 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$ \begin{bmatrix} k_1 \\ k_2\end{bmatrix}  =  (\begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\X_2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} X_1 & X_2\end{bmatrix})^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} X_1\\ X_2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} X_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

And I try some simulations in MATLAB, the $k_1$ and $k_2$ exist. But the first equation is not satisfied.

So I am very confused. I must be wrong. But where? Could anyone tell me?

Comment: From the last three equations, the first is valid. But the rest not.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Could you tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have solved a least square problem finding the projection of $X_3$ onto $span(X_1,X_2)$.

Refer to the related [Is the pseudoinverse matrix the solution to the least squares problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2210789/505767)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the least square problem. But why $k_1$ and $k_2$ exist? Since this violates the definition of linear independence

Comment: $k_1$ and $k_2$ are the solutions of the least squares problem which always has a unique solution since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are linearly independent.

Comment: I mean, $k_1$ and $k_2$ are not zero. If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are linearly independent, the coefficients should be zeroes.

Comment: It is not true for a least square problem. We are solving $k_1X_1+k_2X_2=\bar X_3$ where $\bar X_3$ is projection of $X_3$ onto $span(X_1,X_2)$ and therefore in general $k_1$ and $k_2$ are not zero unless $X_3$ is orthogonal to $span(X_1,X_2) $.

Comment: I see. I understand my wrong. One more question: how could I know that whether the matrix is full rank or not via matrix form?

Comment: @standerQiu As always by $\det(A)$ for "small" matrices or by RREF.

Comment: See. Thank you very much!

Comment: @standerQiu You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score -2):

Your characterization of linear dependence is incorrect. The columns of $X$ are linearly dependent iff there is a nontrivial linear combination $k_1X_1+k_2X_2+k_3X_3$ that vanishes, but this does not let you conclude that $k_1X_1+k_2X_2=X_3$. Consider, for example, $$X=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$ The columns are linearly dependent (every set that contains the zero vector is), but the third column is obviously not a scalar multiple of the first.

If the columns are linearly dependent, then you know that at least one of them is a linear combination of the other two, but you can’t a priori decide which one that is.

Comment: Why the downvote, o drive-by voter?

Comment: $k_1X_1+k_2X_2+k_3X_3$ vanishes means that $k_1X_1+k_2X_2 = X_3$ (scaling)

Comment: @standerQiu No, it doesn’t. Take another look at the simple counterexample above. What value of k1 gives k1(1,0,0)=(0,0,1)? Your “scaling” in that example divides by zero. You’re making the unwarranted assumption that $k_3\ne0$.